# Why does Non-negative Matrix Factorization not give me 100% R^2 at full rank?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, non-negative-matrix-factorization

**IMPORTANT:** Please read the question carefully before labeling it a "code question" & sending it to stack overflow. The question is in fact a theoretical stats question (barring the possibility of a bug in the NMF R library). *Because I can do better than NMF (at full rank) on a positive matrix A, by using the identity transform! i.e. W=A,H=I (identity), s.t. A~=WH. How could NMF possibly be so bad??*

I don't understand why NMF would behave like this while PCA gives perfect invertibility even at much lower rank.

I'm using the R library: [NMF](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-11-367) & NMF method: ["brunet"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15016911/)
**This is my code:**

```
library(NMF)

mass_NMF = nmf(mass_frac_data, rank=ncol(mass_frac_data))
# NOTE: mass_NMF@fit@W==mass_PCA$x, mass_frac_data~=mass_NMF@fit@W%*%mass_NMF@fit@H
cat('NMF R^2 on original data: ', get_explained_var(mass_NMF@fit@W, mass_frac_data))
```

**This is the output:**

`NMF R^2 on original data:  0.9240395` (aka 92%)

(PCA obviously gets approximately 99%, even at much lower rank)

The get_explained_var(X_df, Y_df) function (thoroughly tested) fits linear models to each of the Variables/Columns in Y_df & uses all the variables in the X_df + a bias for predictors (i.e. lm_i = lm(Y_df[,i]~X_df)) then it takes the average of all R^2 values from these linear models.

Comment: The wikipedia page for NMF indicates that "...  if the factorization worked, it is a reasonable approximation to the input matrix V", where "reasonable approximation" does not mean "$R^2 \approx 1$."   Consequently, this would be expected behavior for a non-negative matrix factorization.

Comment: @jbowman: 
I'm basically asking this -- if PCA can do it so easily then why is it hard for NMF?
Also I'm trying to emphasize this point in particular: all the data in mass_frac_data is ALREADY positive. It could've just made each "Factor" correspond to one of the original variables (trivial) & it would've had perfect reconstruction.

Comment: @jbowman: to make things even more clear I can do better than NMF on a (positive matrix) A by doing this: W=A, H=I (identity), s.t. A~=WH. How could NMF possibly be so bad?

Comment: "Current algorithms are sub-optimal in that they only guarantee finding a local minimum, rather than a global minimum of the cost function. A provably optimal algorithm is unlikely in the near future as the problem has been shown to generalize the k-means clustering problem which is known to be NP-complete.[35] However, as in many other data mining applications, a local minimum may still prove to be useful." - from Wikipedia.   My take is that it typically uses an iterative algorithm that relies on a loss function that can have multiple minima; just not very good in this case.

Comment: How does PCA assure non-negativity??

Comment: @whuber It doesn't? Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $X=XI$ is a zero-error NMF factorisation of any non-negative matrix $X$, so the software is not finding the correct optimum.  It's probably not a bug, though.

The NMF problem has local optima, unlike PCA. Even worse, if $X=WH$ is a solution, then $X=WAA^{-1}H$ is another solution exactly as good, as long as $(WA)$ and $(A^{-1}H)$ are non-negative, so even local optima aren't isolated.  In addition, to the extent that the problem is identifiable, it's only because the non-negativity constraints reduce the options, so that many of the optima are right up against the boundary of the parameter space.

It's quite a hard problem, which is why there are so many algorithms in the `NMF` package (if you have six algorithms implemented for something, it's unlikely that any of them is really satisfactory). That's not really surprising. The singular value decomposition underlying PCA is what's unusual here in having a fast globally-convergent algorithm.

The `brunet` algorithm is described [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC384712/). It starts with randomly initialised matrices and does alternating multiplicative updates of the two factors, which apparently works well for low-rank approximations, but you can easily imagine it getting stuck on a high-rank fit.

I tried the various algorithms on a single random matrix of $U[0,1]$ values with rank=number of columns, the `lee` and `ls-nmf` did best in terms of residual mean squared error; you might try them if you want a high-rank solution.

(I worked on a variation of this problem in air pollution, where the goal was to decompose chemistry x time data into chemistry x source and source x time, but with the additional complication that the error variances were all different and poorly estimated)

Comment: Thank you for the sensible & simple answer.
I'm also curious tho: I too am working on a chemistry problem, where I'm making "progress variables" for reduced order modeling (surrogate modeling).

Why can't chemistry people just use PCA (i.e. get negative decompositions)?

Comment: In the air pollution setting the pollution sources are *real things* that they want to estimate, not just a low-rank representation, so there is a lot of interest in using any available constraints to help estimate those things.  I don't know why  more generally.